# How much bandwidth does a Debian server consume when it's idle?

Tags: debian, traffic-management

How much bandwidth as network in/network out would an idle Debian server consume? I assume that a cloud service would compute as traffic port scannings, people trying to log in with default passwords and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough to worry about.

An idle server, of course, will consume no bandwidth. But you seem to be concerned about the traffic from Internet background noise, that is, automated attacks which every IPv4 address receives.

Fortunately for you I happen to have an idle server around, which has been doing nothing but responding to Prometheus scrapes for a while. It has the ssh port open, but nothing else open globally. It really hasn't used much bandwidth.

[image: Data transfer by NIC]